# Mongoid criteria for id

Tags: mongoid

I before the current Mongoid version 2.0.2, I was able to do

User.criteria.id( 1234 ) #=> user#1234

But now it throws a no method error. Has this been changed to something else or has it been removed?

Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, they (mongoid team) did remove the criteria#id selector from the latest version of mongoid. The reason why I don't use Model.find is because it doesn't do lazy loading, where criteria#id does. But back to the issue here. They replaced criteria#id with criteria#for_ids

So Model.criteria.for_ids('1234') will work

Answer (score 2):

You could always do this:

```
User.where(:conditions => {:id => '1234'})
```

Or if you didn't actually need a criteria object (and just wanted the user with id '1234') you could just do:

```
User.find('1234')
```

Comment: Thanks theTRON, I dug into the github page for mongoid issues and found the answer, please see my answer below if you are interested